# How to use importlib with a list instead of 'from x import x'

Tags: python, import, module, python-importlib, import-module

I am updating my code to include Try and Except statements to make it more robust. My current implementation is lots of separate try and except statements each with individual import statements:

```
try:
    from Helpers import editorfunctions

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print(sys.exc_info())

try:
    from Helpers import datamanipulation

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print(sys.exc_info())

try:
    from DefaultFolderStructure import defaultfolderstructure

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print(sys.exc_info())
```

This is quite messy and I want to reformat it to be a loop that runs through a list - Something a bit  like this:

```
libs = ['Helpers.editorfunctions', 'Helpers.datamanipulation', "DefaultFolderStructure.defaultfolderstructure"]

for lib in libs:
    try:
        lib = import_module(lib)

    except:
        print(sys.exc_info())
```

The current sudo code above does not work, I'm wondering how I can get it working?

All of the modules I am importing are within child folders of the current directory.

I've tried using sys.path.append("..") so the module_import() can find the package and import the modules in the list but I know I'm missing something!. Any help would be very appreciated thanks.

Comment: Will your code still work if these modules are missing and you've caught the import errors? If not, then you're redundantly try/catching as these errors will already be printed out if the module is missing at runtime.

Comment: @Stephen Yes my code will still work if the module is missing or there is an error. I just tested it by introducing a syntax error and the rest of the imports still worked. So this method should work if I'm importing from a list or using my current implementation.

Comment: You've said that using `importlib.__import__(name)` doesn't work. Show us what you've tried, because it should work.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Here is my current code - I am getting an undefined module error after it runs.

'
    import sys
import importlib
 
sys.path.append("..")
 
libs = ['Helpers.editorfunctions', 'Helpers.datamanipulation']
 
for lib in libs:
    try:
        lib = importlib.__import__(lib)
 
    except:
        print(sys.exc_info())
'